# Not able to install Office developer tools for VS Express 2012 for Desktop and Win 7 x64

Tags: visual-studio, ms-office

I want to develop Office 2010/2013 Add In. I have Win 7 x64 machine which is not connected to Internet, so I downloaded all the setups required for Office development and tried to install them on the machine as explained [here](http://download.microsoft.com/download/D/B/D/DBD439A9-370D-40EA-B3B7-45CD935B98FB/WFTools/en/WorkflowManagerTools_x64.msi).

I have Office 2010 installed on this machine.

I had following difficulties.

- While installing MicrosoftIdentityExtensions-64.msi it said it needs "Microsoft Identity Foundation". So I explicitly downloaded and installed Windows6.1-KB974405-x64.msu
- While installing WorkflowManagerTools_x64.msi it said it needs Microsoft Visual Studio 2012, though I have installed VS Express 2012 for Desktop. Does it require full blown VS? Isnt it done on VS Express? So am absolutely not able to intall this WorkflowManagerTools_x64.msi

[image]

- Also while installing officetools_bundle.exe the setup says it requires Visual Studio Web Developer tools for Visual Studio 2012, though it allowed to continue the setup.

After installing all other setups said at the link and with above problems am still not getting Office Add In template in New Project window of VS

- Can I develop Office 2013 add in using VS Express 2012 for Desktop on Win 7 x64 machine or Add In for Office 2010 will work without any problem on Office 2013.
- Do I need full VS 2012 to do Office development?

To be specific I want to develop some Outlook Add In.

Comment: i have this exact question basically

Answer (score 0):

For Office Add-In Development you need Visual Studio Professional or Above.
VSTO is not supported by VS Express version.